# Club XML nodes together based on similar subtags. The clubbed node should also contain the non-similar subtags

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

**I have just started learning xslt , please forgive me for for asking a straight solution.**

I want to club `<Record>` tags data into `<Webservice>` tag which have common `<Employee_ID>` , `<Change_Reason_Code>` , `<Effective_Date>`. The remaining data , which can be different or same , to come in `<Allowance>` tags, inside the `<Webservice>` tag.

Example: In the xml , EMPONE has 3 `<Record>` tags. Two of these tags have same value for  `<Employee_ID>` , `<Change_Reason_Code>` , `<Effective_Date>` but for the third the `<Effective_Date>` is different. So the output has 2 `<Webservice>` tags for EMPONE.
What XSLT code will do this?

XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <File>
    <Record>

        <Employee_ID>EMPONE</Employee_ID>
        <Change_Reason_Code>REASONONE</Change_Reason_Code>
        <Effective_Date>2020-01-01</Effective_Date>
        
        <Plan_Code>Plan1</Plan_Code>
        <Plan_Amount>100</Plan_Amount>
        <Plan_Currency_Code>USD</Plan_Currency_Code>
        <Plan_Frequency>Monthly</Plan_Frequency> 
    </Record>
    <Record>

        <Employee_ID>EMPONE</Employee_ID>
        <Change_Reason_Code>REASONONE</Change_Reason_Code>
        <Effective_Date>2020-01-01</Effective_Date>
        
        <Plan_Code>Plan2</Plan_Code>
        <Plan_Amount>200</Plan_Amount>
        <Plan_Currency_Code>AUD</Plan_Currency_Code>
        <Plan_Frequency>Yearly</Plan_Frequency> 
    </Record>
    <Record>

        <Employee_ID>EMPONE</Employee_ID>
        <Change_Reason_Code>REASONONE</Change_Reason_Code>
        <Effective_Date>2020-01-02</Effective_Date>
        
        <Plan_Code>Plan2</Plan_Code>
        <Plan_Amount>200</Plan_Amount>
        <Plan_Currency_Code>AUD</Plan_Currency_Code>
        <Plan_Frequency>Yearly</Plan_Frequency> 
    </Record>
        <Record>

        <Employee_ID>EMPTWO</Employee_ID>
        <Change_Reason_Code>REASONONE</Change_Reason_Code>
        <Effective_Date>2020-01-02</Effective_Date>
        
        <Plan_Code>Plan2</Plan_Code>
        <Plan_Amount>200</Plan_Amount>
        <Plan_Currency_Code>AUD</Plan_Currency_Code>
        <Plan_Frequency>Yearly</Plan_Frequency> 
    </Record>
</File>
```

Desired Output :

```
<File>
<Webservice>

    <Employee_ID>EMPONE</Employee_ID>
    <Change_Reason_Code>REASONONE</Change_Reason_Code>
    <Effective_Date>2020-01-01</Effective_Date>

    <Allowance>
        <Plan_Code>Plan1</Plan_Code>
        <Plan_Amount>100</Plan_Amount>
        <Plan_Currency_Code>USD</Plan_Currency_Code>
        <Plan_Frequency>Monthly</Plan_Frequency> 
    </Allowance>        
    <Allowance>
        <Plan_Code>Plan2</Plan_Code>
        <Plan_Amount>200</Plan_Amount>
        <Plan_Currency_Code>AUD</Plan_Currency_Code>
        <Plan_Frequency>Yearly</Plan_Frequency> 
    </Allowance>        


</Webservice>
<Webservice>
    <Employee_ID>EMPONE</Employee_ID>
    <Change_Reason_Code>REASONONE</Change_Reason_Code>
    <Effective_Date>2020-01-02</Effective_Date>

    <Allowance>
        <Plan_Code>Plan2</Plan_Code>
        <Plan_Amount>200</Plan_Amount>
        <Plan_Currency_Code>AUD</Plan_Currency_Code>
        <Plan_Frequency>Yearly</Plan_Frequency> 
    </Allowance>        
</Webservice>

<Webservice>
    <Employee_ID>EMPTWO</Employee_ID>
    <Change_Reason_Code>REASONONE</Change_Reason_Code>
    <Effective_Date>2020-01-02</Effective_Date>

    <Allowance>
        <Plan_Code>Plan2</Plan_Code>
        <Plan_Amount>200</Plan_Amount>
        <Plan_Currency_Code>AUD</Plan_Currency_Code>
        <Plan_Frequency>Yearly</Plan_Frequency> 
    </Allowance>        
</Webservice>

</File>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info or your favourite XSLT tutorial on grouping.

Comment: Clubbing XML nodes can damage the structure of an XML document and is not recommended.  On the other hand, taking XML nodes to nightclubs can be a lot of fun.

Comment: @kjhughes Nightclubs is done  :) , I can manage the recommendation , give me the xslt   ..haha